# Math/Subtraction is different between Formula field and Apex

Tags: apex, formula

I have a Formula field which does simple subtraction between two other fields.

Field X - Formula (return type Number, 2 decimal places).

Field Y - Currency(16, 2)

The formula field simply does : `X - Y`. It is Currency return type,

I'm seeing differences in math when replicating what the Formula field does (simple subtraction in Apex).

When X and Y are both `-0.01`, the difference should be `0.00`

Formula Field computes to   : `0.01`

Apex Subtraction computes to: `0.00`

The above values were printed using `System.debug`.

I know [Currency's round "half-even" by default](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=choosing_a_formula_data_type.htm&type=5), but even when using `System.RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN` on both X and Y, the Apex calculation is still rightfully `0`.

Any help is appreciated!

```
// obj.X - Formula (Return type Number, 2 decimal places.)
// obj.Y - Currency (16,2) 16 length, 2 decimal places.
// obj.Z - Formula (Currency, 2 decimal places) - `X - Y`
System.debug(obj.X);            //X prints -0.01
System.debug(obj.Y);            //Y prints -0.01
System.debug('MANUAL MATH');
System.debug(obj.X - obj.Y);    //Apex math prints 0.00
System.debug('Formula field');
System.debug(obj.Z);            //Z prints 0.01
```

Comment: Can you share more of the Apex code you are using

Comment: @BryanAnderson sure, I basically put what i was doing in anonymous apex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am getting this (sorry I couldn't put this all in a comment):

```
test_Object__c obj = [Select xfld__c,yfld__c,zfld__c From test_Object__c WHERE Name = 'test'];

System.debug(obj.xfld__c);            //X prints -0.01
System.debug(obj.yfld__c);            //Y prints -0.01
System.debug('MANUAL MATH');
System.debug(obj.xfld__c - obj.yfld__c);    //Apex math prints 0.00
System.debug('Formula field');
System.debug(obj.zfld__c);
```

Results:
[image: 1]

xfld__c:
[image]

yfld__c:
[image]

zfld__c:
[image]

Comment: I replicated this too, and the same outcome. 

This means that system.debug is not giving me the truth when it comes to logging the values of X and Y in the actual system. Or dark magic. :(

Comment: So wait, Im not understanding, your question said it was wrong, but now you are getting the same result as me. So which is it?

Comment: The calculations are correct whenever I make an entirely new object, just like you did. 

However in my original object (which has much more cruft, etc), the formula field is calculating wrong. While the formula field is simple subtraction (just like you have in `zfld__c`), it is calculating to be `0.01`, instead of `0.00`. 

This is despite the X and Y of that formula both being `-0.01` per `System.debug` each field...

I wonder if System.debug truncates somehow by default? seems like a silly notion.

Comment: Is there anyway you can show a workbench query of the exact records in question

Comment: Sure. --- Values in order of Object ID, X, Y, and Z perspectively.

a5x19000000KDJsAAO -0.01 -0.01 0.01

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer now and probably put in a case with Salesforce. Will update if i get anything.

Comment: Sorry I meant a screenshot in your original question to see if SF is storing any unknown precision

Comment: Back with some good tidbits of knowledge! 

There's a few whacky things I discovered. 

First: For whatever reason (salesforce design?) the precision set on formula fields  does not seem to evaluated whenever the field is used in another formula. 

In this case, X in my sandbox was actually a value of `-0.005`, and when viewed via apex/sqol it would evaluate the precision, showing `-0.01`. Whenever used in formula field Z though, the precision would not be evaluated for X or Y before the math occurred.

Comment: Another tidbit is that Salesforce has some incorrect docs... `-0.005` was rounding "down" to `-0.01`.  
The docs below state this should be rounding to 0.0. 

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tips_for_using_number_formula_fields.htm&type=5